# Get paperclip full url in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I publish some data in redis after saving my model and I need send full url of attachment to Redis, but I'm stuck to get rails root url with port or full attachment url.
How I can get full url of paperclip attachments or get rails app root url  in model file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Models don't know how you deploy the application. However controllers do via `request` object:

```
"#{request.protocol}#{request.host}"
```

You could pass it to the model level, however it breaks the abstraction badly.

I would consider changing the design.

Answer (score 0):

The use case is also in web sockets. Use `#{request.host} or #{request.port} or #{request.protocol} or #{request.params}` to get the necessary request information. @Danil answer is the right string interpolation for the question.